# How do I loop over the output of `pushd` in Windows Command Processor?

Tags: for-loop, cmd, pushd

The following illustrates a problem I found using `for /f %l in ('<command>') do @(echo %l)`. (`/f` is the `for` command's parameter for "iterating and file parsing.") This works as expected when `<command>` is `cd` or `chdir`, but not when `<command>` is `pushd`:

```
C:\>cd
C:\

C:\>for /f %l in ('cd') do @(echo %l)
C:\

C:\>chdir
C:\

C:\>for /f %l in ('chdir') do @(echo %l)
C:\

C:\>pushd Windows

C:\Windows>pushd
C:\

C:\Windows>for /f %l in ('pushd') do @(echo %l)

C:\Windows>pushd > nul

C:\Windows>
```

I would expect the last command to print `C:\` but it does not execute the `do` block at all. I added `pushd > nul` to check that `pushd` prints to `stdout`.

How can I process the output of [`pushd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/pushd) in a [`for /f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for) loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Information about command processing by FOR /F

The usage of a `for /F` loop with a **command** enclosed in `'` or in `` ` `` on using `usebackq` results in starting in background one more command process using `%ComSpec% /c` and the **command** appended as additional argument(s).

The usage of `for /f %l in ('pushd') do @(echo %l)` results in background execution of:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c pushd
```

That can be seen by downloading, extracting and running the free Windows Sysinternals tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) as administrator which logs the execution of **two** `cmd.exe` processes with different process identifiers on running the commands as posted in the question. There must be double clicked on any line in log of *Process Monitor* of second `cmd.exe` in the middle of the log to open the **Event Properties** window and selected the second tab **Process** to see the *Command Line* which was used by first `cmd.exe` to start the second `cmd.exe` for the execution of the **command** `pushd`.

There cannot be executed just a single **command** with a `for /F` loop. There can be executed an entire **command line** which can even have [multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564). But it is necessary to take into account all the information given by the usage help of `cmd` output on running `cmd /?` in a command prompt window on using a complex **command line** with `for /F` and processing its output as written to handle **STDOUT** of in background started `cmd.exe`.

Command operators like `&`, `&&` and `||` as well as [redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) like `|`, `2>` and `2>&1` in the **command line** to execute by `for /F` are processed by two `cmd.exe`, first the one executing the entire `for /F` loop and another one started in background with the **command line** of which output is of interest. That is the reason why many `for /F` loops with a complex **command line** are with the escape character `^` left to each `&` and `|` and `>` in the **command line** to get these characters interpreted literally by `cmd.exe` parsing and executing the entire `for /F` loop while being interpreted as command/redirection operators by the second `cmd.exe` started in background which is really executing the **command line**.

---

### Information about output of PUSHD

The [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands) **PUSHD** outputs on execution without any directory path the list of directory paths pushed on stack of **current** command process.

There can be executed in a command prompt window following commands:

```
cd /D %SystemDrive%\
pushd %SystemRoot%
pushd inf
pushd
popd
popd
```

The fifth command `pushd` results usually for typical Windows installations in the output:

```
C:\Windows
C:\
```

But there is nothing output by using as fifth command instead of `pushd` the command line:

```
for /F "delims=" %I in ('pushd') do @echo %I
```

The reason is the execution of `pushd` by one more `cmd.exe` started in background which has no directory paths pushed on its stack. The internal command **PUSHD** does not output anything at all for that reason to handle **STDOUT** of in background started `cmd.exe`.

The command process running `for /F` cannot capture any output text. The `for /F` loop cannot process therefore any line after `cmd.exe` started in background finished the execution of `pushd` and closed itself.

---

### How to process the directory paths pushed on stack?

It would be necessary to use the following command lines in the command prompt window to process the directory paths pushed on stack of the **current** command process:

```
pushd >"%TEMP%\DirectoryList.tmp"
if exist "%TEMP%\DirectoryList.tmp" for /F "usebackq delims=" %I in ("%TEMP%\DirectoryList.txt") do @echo %I
del "%TEMP%\DirectoryList.tmp" 2>nul
```

The redirection of the output of **PUSHD** executed by the command process which executed also the two `pushd` command lines before into a temporary file makes it possible to process the directory paths pushed on stack of **current** command process.

The `for /F` option `usebackq` is necessary to get the string inside `"` interpreted as file name of which lines to process by the **FOR** loop and not as string to process.

The `for /F` option `delims=` is necessary to define an empty list of string delimiters as a directory path can contain one or more spaces. There is by default split up a line into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab as string delimiters and assigned to the loop variable is just the first space/tab delimited string instead of the entire directory path. The line splitting is turned off by the definition of an empty list of delimiters. The entire directory path is assigned therefore always to the loop variable in this case with processing always full directory paths never starting with the default end of line character `;` as the first character is always either a drive letter or a backslash in case of a UNC directory path.

---

### Why does the command **CD** work with a  FOR /F loop?

The command **CD** works also with `for /F "delims=" %I in ('cd') do @echo %I` because of `cmd.exe` calls the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) on starting the additional command process for execution of a **command** specified as set of a `for /F` loop with value **NULL** for the function parameter `lpCurrentDirectory`. The current directory of in background started `cmd.exe` is set by `CreateProcess` for that reason with the current directory of the command process executing the `for /F` command line. Both running command processes have the same current directory during the execution of the **command** of a `for /F` loop.

---

### Information about environment variable ComSpec

`ComSpec` is an environment variable defined by default with `%SystemRoot%\system32\cmd.exe` (with `s` at beginning of `System32` instead of `S` as the folder name is in real by default) as **system** environment variable stored in Windows registry under the key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.

It is really not advisable to ever modify or even delete the environment variable `ComSpec` neither in **local** environment of a running process nor in the Windows registry. That would cause a lot of programs to stop working normally as lots of executables depend internally on the correct definition of this environment variable including `cmd.exe` itself.

The reason is that many applications and scripts use internally the function [system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem) which uses the environment variable `ComSpec` to start on Windows `cmd.exe` for execution of a command line.

There are many batch files running internal command `ver` of `cmd.exe` to get the Windows version like:

```
for /F "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%G in ('ver') do for /F "tokens=2" %%H in ("%%G") do echo %%H
```

That works only for Windows NT based Windows versions using `cmd.exe` as command processor and not for older Windows versions using `COMMAND.COM` like Windows 95/98/ME for processing a batch file. It works only with enabled command extensions which are enabled by Windows default, but can be disabled by command `setlocal DisableExtension` in a batch file, on starting `cmd.exe` with `/E:OFF` or by a registry value which should be really never used and therefore not written here. The command `ver` must be really executed by `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` because of in real is output the version of `cmd.exe` and not the version of Windows.

However, that command line is very good to demonstrate what happens on usage of `for /F` if the environment variable `ComSpec` is not defined in environment of `cmd.exe` on running the batch file with the two `for /F` loops.

#### ComSpec usage by cmd.exe on Windows XP

On Windows XP is always called `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c ver` even on doing following:

1. Copying `cmd.exe` to the directory `F:\Temp\system32`.
2. Starting `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` with a double click in *Windows Explorer*.
3. Running `set ComSpec=F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` and `set SystemRoot=F:\Temp` and `set SystemDrive=F:` and `set windir=F:\Temp`.
4. Verifying with `echo %__APPDIR__%` that `F:\Temp\system32\` is output.
5. Running the batch file with the command line as posted above.

That can be seen with *Process Monitor* v3.61 on Windows XP x86.

There can be even modified the **local** environment variable `PATH` to begin with `F:\Temp\system32` instead of `C:\WINDOWS\system32` or the **local** environment variable `ComSpec` is deleted with `set ComSpec=`. The Windows Command Processor of Windows XP in directory `F:\Temp\system32` calls nevertheless always `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe` with the option `/c` and the command `ver` on running the batch file immediately after closing the batch file containing just the single command line in the text editor.

There cannot be seen in *Process Monitor* even a Windows registry access by `cmd.exe` of Windows XP to get any directory path.

Please read further why `cmd.exe` of Windows XP in a different directory than `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` calls nevertheless the command processor executable in Windows system directory even after modification of **local** environment variable `ComSpec` or its deletion.

#### ComSpec usage of cmd.exe on Windows Vista/7/8/8.1/10/11

The same procedure as described above for Windows XP can be executed also on Windows 7 x64 and newer 64-bit Windows versions.

The double clicked 64-bit `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` copied from `C:\Windows\System32` outputs on Windows 7 and currently latest Windows 11 22H2 first:

> The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2350 in the message file for Application.
>
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

**Note:** The copyright message line depends on version of `cmd.exe`. The output above is from `cmd.exe` of version 10.0.22621.963 (Windows 11 22H2).

The Windows Command Processor `cmd.exe` of version 6.1.7601 of Windows 7 outputs additionally the line:

> Not enough storage is available to process this command.

The execution of the internal command `ver` executed in the command prompt window opened with a double click on `F:\Temp\System32\cmd.exe` fails on Windows 7 and all later Windows versions up to currently latest Windows 11 22H2 which is the reason for the strange output on starting `F:\Temp\System32\cmd.exe` with a double click.

There can be redefined also the environment variables as described above and done on German Windows XP by me on my tests. A verification of the output of `echo %__APPDIR__%` works and shows `F:\Temp\system32\` as expected. So, it works to access the string value of the internal **dynamic** variable of `cmd.exe` even on executed `cmd.exe` is not in the directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`.

But the batch file execution from within the command prompt of `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` as on Windows XP results in no output at all.

In log of *Process Monitor* v3.70 or a newer *Process Monitor* version can be seen that on Windows 7 and Windows 11 22H2 is executed `F:\Temp\System32\cmd.exe /c ver`. That means it is indeed possible that another `cmd.exe` is executed instead of `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` on Windows 7 and newer Windows versions.

But why is no version output?

Well, the execution of `ver` results in the output of the error message:

> The system cannot find message text for message number 0x2350 in the message file for Application.

64-bit `cmd.exe` is not working in `F:\Temp\system32` at all.

The usage of 32-bit `cmd.exe` copied from `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` to `F:\Temp\system32` makes no difference. The same error messages are output already on starting `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` and on running next `ver` or the batch file after modification of **local** environment variable `ComSpec`.

**Conclusion:** `cmd.exe` of Windows Vista and newer versions are not fully working on being stored outside the appropriate system directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` or `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64` while `cmd.exe` of Windows XP works fine in any directory.

#### Caching of ComSpec value

I found out with lots of further tests that the string value of the environment variable `ComSpec` is indeed used to find `cmd.exe` to run command `ver` on execution of the batch file with the `for /F` loop. But there is a caching mechanism on Windows Vista and newer Windows versions.

There must be run immediately `set ComSpec=F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` after starting `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` before running the batch file. This results in calling `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe /c ver`. If there is next executed `set ComSpec=C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` to redefine the variable with correct value and run the batch file once again, there is nevertheless run now not working `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe /c ver`.

The same caching mechanism can be seen on starting `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe`, then running the batch file resulting in calling in background `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ver`, next running `set ComSpec=F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe` and running now the batch file again. There is executed once again `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c ver` although the value of the environment variable `ComSpec` is now `F:\Temp\system32\cmd.exe`.

It looks like `cmd.exe` of Windows Vista/7/8/8.1/10/11 reads the value of `ComSpec` only once and keeps its value in memory for further usage without reading the environment variable a second time on string value for the default command interpreter being already in its internal memory.

That is quite clever in my opinion. The string value of `ComSpec` is read only once from the environment variable on first usage and then is used that string internally on further usage because of the value of the environment variable `ComSpec` changes usually never as long as `cmd.exe` is running.

It looks like `cmd.exe` of Windows XP has nearly the same caching mechanism for the string value of the environment variable `ComSpec`. The difference is that `cmd.exe` of `Windows XP` reads the value of `ComSpec` already on starting it and not on first usage and so all changes done on **local** environment variable `ComSpec` of an already running `cmd.exe` have no effect on the execution of one more `cmd.exe` on processing a `for /F` loop with a command line to execute, capturing the output and processing it as I could find out with further tests on German Windows XP.